# Error in Command Line in magento 2

Tags: magento, cmd

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUZFy.jpg) Hi i have USE CMD for flush magento cache. He give me Error php is not recognized as an internal or extenal command, operable program or batch file.

I am use all setting like

Go to My computer ->click on properties click on Advacnce System Setting than Environment variables than add User Variable and System Variable and added Path
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini but not working Properly.

Give me the solution for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do following in you system

```
System>Advanced  System Settings>Environment Variables
Click new

Variable name  : path
Variable value : c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\


Click ok
```

You need not to point to php.ini